# Tensorflow hub.load Model to TFLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a model loaded with hub.load to TFLite.
The model in question is universal-sentence-encoder (4) found at https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4
I tried in Python with Tensorflow version 2.1.0 and 2.2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model )
converter.experimental_new_converter = True // tried with and without
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I get the following error:

```
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 394, in from_keras_model
    if not isinstance(model.call, _def_function.Function):
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'call'
```

From my understanding hub.load return a keras SavedModel, so shouldn't be convertible right away?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `hub.KerasLayer` to load your model into a `tf.keras.Model` and then convert it to `ŧflite` using `.from_keras_model`.

There's no such thing as a "keras SavedModel". There's the `SavedModel`, which is `.pb` file + `assets` folder + `variables` folder. It's like a file format, a way to store your model. It has nothing to do with the in memory `tf.keras.Model`s. `hub.load` does not return a `tf.keras.Model`, but rather "the most generic thing" you can save in the `SavedModel` file format, namely a `_UserObject`. This is because you can save other things than just `tf.keras.Models`s in a `SavedModel`s file format.

I know this was not your question, but if you *do* want to get your `tf.keras.Model` back after loading, you can use `tf.keras.save_model` to save it. Then it will come back as a `tf.keras.Model` after loading using `tf.saved_model.load` (so then it's no longer the most generic thing).

EDIT:

Just the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(dtype=tf.string, input_shape=()))
model.add(hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

which works (it starts converting), but you get a:

```
2020-05-05 10:48:44.927433: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:659] Converting unsupported operation: StatefulPartitionedCall
```

So this *is* the code to convert models saved in `SavedModel` format to `tflite`, but you get a `google-universal-sentence-encoder` specific error. No idea how to fix that tough.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, I tried 
tf.saved_model.save(model, filepath) and then model = tf.saved_model.load(filepath), 
but the error persist.

I tried using KerasLayer, but it keeps giving me error on the input size

Comment: Thanks, now it is clearer how to use KerasLayer.
I tried and it gives me the same error, the error change if you add converter.experimental_new_converter = True 

I found out that there are other people with the same issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34396