# Convert tf_hub models to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to convert a tf_hub model (MUSE) to tflite, but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundError` which is very strange, and I have no idea how to interpret the error message. Here are my code and the error message:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(dtype=tf.string, input_shape=()))
model.add(hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3"))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS,  # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

And the error I got:

```
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceOp' in binary running on hongtao-mac. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
 If trying to load on a different device from the computational device, consider using setting the `experimental_io_device` option on tf.saved_model.LoadOptions to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.
```

Any ideas?

Note: possibly related question: [Tensorflow hub.load Model to TFLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61595909/tensorflow-hub-load-model-to-tflite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation at https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3 states that you need to install `tensorflow-text` and import it before loading a model. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert says that it's recommended to use `from_saved_model` instead of `from_keras_model`. The following works for me in a fresh Colab:

```py
!pip install -q tensorflow-text
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text

hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3")  # Caches the model in /tmp/tfhub_modules
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/tmp/tfhub_modules/26c892ffbc8d7b032f5a95f316e2841ed4f1608c")
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS,  # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_file = "model.tflite"
with open(tflite_file, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(converter.convert())
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(tflite_file)
interpreter.get_signature_list()  # {'serving_default': {'inputs': ['inputs'], 'outputs': ['outputs']}}
```